# pandas map makes values NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nan

I'm trying to map my values that i want to change.
When i apply 'map' like this >> df[column].map(dictionary), the values that are not in the dictionary convert to NaN. I think the reason is that there are no matched values in the series, right? If so, nothing should be applied instead converting to NaN? How can i solve this problem using df.map() instead of df.replace()?

```
df1 = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])
df
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
dtype: object

mapping = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 2}
df1.map(mapping)
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

or

```
df1 = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])
df
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
dtype: object

mapping = {'k' : 0, 'e' : 1, 'f' : 2}
df1.map(mapping)

0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: "How can i solve this problem using df.map() instead of df.replace()?" <- I don't understand.  It sounds like you already know that `replace` has the behaviour you want.  Why do you think you need to use `map`?

Comment: Actually, it just for my coding skill. I want to know that map can handle those problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is intended. Since `mapping` can not be applied the value is `NaN`.
In order to use mapping you have to create a specific value that does not change your data (if you do multiplication that would be 1, if you do addition then 0) and add that value to your mapping.

Alternatively you could replace all `NaN` values after you have done the mapping with a neutral value like 0.0.

Either way is much more work then to simply use `replace`.

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on `map` pass a callable instead

```
df.map(lambda x: mapping.get(x,x))
```

Comment: gosh dang that is a great answer. ty sir

Comment: This is an excellent solution for cases where the `x` value is a float (e.g. `100.000000002`), and the lookup value is `100.00`.  By adding a `round(x, n)` function, the mapping works.

Comment: Hi Could you elaborate more about this get(), please?

Answer (score 2):

To change the default value, you could add a function (func, here):

```
mapping = {'k' : 0, 'e' : 1, 'f' : 2}
mapping.setdefault('Default', 'write watherver you want here')
def func(x, mapping):
    try:
        tmp=mapping[x]
        return(tmp)
    except:
        return('default value')
df1.map(lambda x: func(x, mapping))
```